# How can I use eclipse code style to highlight my code in wordpress

Tags: eclipse, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to use Easy Google Syntax Highlighter in my wordpress blog. Because often I will paste some java code in my blog. But I don't like the default style of Easy Google Syntax Highlighter, how can I use the eclipse java code style ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend keeping an eye out for a good Pygments plugin for Wordpress.

The following URL is a blog post by Gwynne Raskind talking about a Pygments plugin she's made but has not released yet - it's currently pending clarification on licensing and the post was written **just yesterday** so it's definitely alive.

http://blog.darkrainfall.org/highlighting-source-code-in-wordpress-with-pygments/

EDIT: I know it's not "eclipse style" but to get Eclipse-style syntax highlighting you'll likely have to rewrite stuff on your own. Since Pygments highlighting is crazy-awesome I thought this might be a good alternative.

ANOTHER EDIT: **If you use java**, http://www.java2html.de/applet.html might be useful!

Comment: One style for pygments is available at https://github.com/soundasleep/iaml/blob/master/org.openiaml.docs.tools/latex/eclipse.py

Answer (score 0):

You may have to edit the language files, in the /Scripts folder. There appears to be no quick way to 'theme' it though and looking at the files it would be a time consuming process to edit the colors for each language.